# Disable attack cool down in Minecraft Vanilla 1.9/1.10 server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a small server (in 1.8 at the moment) and am thinking about upgrading to 1.9 or 1.10.

But the most important thing: I don't want to have any kind of "cool down" during attacking.
Is there any way to remove it in Vanilla?

Might there be a better way than [this youtube tutorial](http://bit.ly/1U7tNCE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First place a command block and paste in this command:

   ```
   /replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head minecraft:wooden_button 1 0 {AttributeModifiers [{AttributeName:"generic.attackSpeed",Name:generic.attackSpeed,Amount:99999999,Operation:0,UUIDMost:90498,UUIDLeast:161150}]}
   ```
2. Place a button on the command block and press it.
3. You should have a button automatically placed in your helmet slot.
4. No Cooldown!

Comment: Use the /attribute command to add attributes to players without items

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad idea, as axes will be super OP.
But if you don't give a damn about fighting balance, you could do it by giving an item that would give attack speed, like this:

```
/give @p minecraft:structure_void 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.attackSpeed",Name:"generic.attackSpeed",Amount:99999,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:325144,UUIDMost:12368}],display:{Name:"SimpleFighting"}}
```